# Search git history for commits made in the night or in Saturday

Tags: git, git-log

Github have a [punchcard](https://github.com/rails/rails/graphs/punch-card) that display at what time the commits were done, but doesn't show which commits were done in that hour.

Is there any easy way to search the `git log` for commits made in a time interval (not for a specific date).

Just to make it clear, I'm **not** looking for commits made in a certain date, instead of that I want to find all the commits made between 10pm and 5am on any date.

Can it be done without using a super custom script?

Answer (score 7):

Late to the party, but here's what worked for me, A little hacky with the list of hours but...

```
git log --all --date=iso-local --pretty=format:"The author of %h was %an, %ad" | grep -E "( 22:)|( 23:)|( 00:)|( 01:)|( 02:)|( 03:)|( 04:)"
```

Can tweak pretty format to display what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h %s" --relative-date --graph
```

for more details pleas check [Git Basics - Viewing the Commit History](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History)

Answer (score 0):

The format given by yaitloutou was not working for me, but to search for late commits I've used:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%ad %h %s" --date=format:%H | sort
```

%ad is the date, and it respect the format given by the `--date` argument (that use strftime)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$ git log --since=1.day.ago                      # commits since 1 day ago to now ago
$ git log --since=3.day.ago --untill=2.day.ago   # commits on 2 days ago (just one day)
$ git log --since=5-12-16                        # specify a date
```

Comment: I don't want to search commits by date, what I want is to find commits made in the night, not "last night", any night.